# Non-mapped faces/vertices taking color from pixel 0,0; what is the best solution?

Tags: uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

When faces aren't mapped Blender *internally* collapses them to [0;0] in the UV Editor canvas, i.e. they are going to take color from the pixel [0;0]. (While this can be hard to detect it makes sense.)

Is there a better solution other than making the [0;0] pixel in the image file actually transparent? (Sometimes there's no way of placing the unwanted vertices aside, namely when combining mappings from several meshes in one material.)

Is there a way to tell Blender to pretend such non-mapped faces/vertices are sitting at pixel with total transparency, or just to ignore them somehow...?

Comment: Shouldn't you just go ahead and map them?  Or, if you don't want them to ever be visible, delete the faces?  But sure, you could mix with some value on the basis of UV.x  is not greater than 0 and UV.y is not greater than 0-- just, why?

Comment: I have one material that is used on several meshes, on each it displays different decal i.e. a different image/mapping. That's why in my case it does not make sense to map those faces. At least I don't know how to tell Blender in meshA->uvMap1 that faces from meshB should be moved aside off of the bitmap rectangle.

Comment: If you don't want those faces to display the decal, map them to a transparent part of the decal.  This can be out of 0,1 bounds, with a image texture set to extend/clip, if you'd like.  With a file and specifics about your end goal, I could probably give more info.

Comment: Like I said in the original question, IMO there's no way of mapping those when combining mappings of several meshes in one material.

Comment: I can imagine it is not very clear when explained like this, I might create a showcase blender-file to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: AFAIK, once you create a UV map, it assigns all loops (vertices per face) to that map. The default value is 0;0. So it's not like some loops are not mapped - all are, some may not be unwrapped, but what unwrapping does is move the UV coordinates of the loops. There's no way to tell apart a loop pointing to 0;0 and unwrapped and a loop that points there because it was never unwrapped. And so, the only solution available is, if you don't want to modify the image texture but still you don't use the bottom-left corner - then you can have a shader that sets alpha based on UV distance from 0;0.

Comment: Well OK, perhaps you can check if a loop is connected to other loops also mapped to 0;0. But is a Python script a valid option? Not sure about your workflow.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady If you just check in shader for equality with 0,0, which occupies an infinitesimal space at most of any face, then you're golden: you'll only get samples of faces that have all corners mapped to 0,0.  Yes, zoomed in far enough, there's a chance that a particular sample will map to that anyways, but it's not realistic.  But I still don't think this is the right answer to the problem, and want to see the example where this is necessary, because I think that there's probably a better solution and that this is likely to be an XY problem.

Comment: @Nathan you're correct, I didn't connect the dots I myself drawn: since only a single loop of each unwrapped face can sit on 0;0, less than 0,[73 zeroes]... % of the normalized UV space will be affected... Or one in 10^75 samples.